# Why dont my grid system work when I use include() instead of Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a fetch_comment.php file which fetchs database rows and I have another page index.php which will display the result.I used to display the results with an Ajax call like this

```
function load_comment(){
$.ajax({
url:"fetch_comment.php",
method:"POST",
success:function(data)
{$('#display_comment').html(data);}
})
}
load_comment();
```

And this was working fine.But now,instead of using Ajax (which is unnecessary in my case) I tried to include fetch_comment.php directly like this

```
<div id="display_comment"> <?php include("fetch_comment.php"); ?> </div>
```

But now all my Bootstrap grid system is a mess.I didnt make any changes on fetch_comment.php .So why is it working fine with Ajax but loses styling when I use include() function?

Here is the fetch_comment.php code aslo:

```
    <style>
.arrows{
    float:left;
}

</style>
<?php
include("timeAgo.php");

        $query="SELECT * FROM comments 
        WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' AND onay=1 AND kategori <> 'Argo Serbest' AND kategori <> 'Cinsi Kıpraşmalar'
        ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 10;";




$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
foreach($result as $row){
    $post_head = str_replace('_',' ',$row["post_head"]);
    if(strlen($row["comment"])>=400){
        $readmore='  <span style="font-family: Germania One, cursive;color:#0275d8;">......Konuya Git</span>';
    }
    else{$readmore="";}


 echo '
 <div class="postBox">
 <div class="innerBox2">


  <div class="displaySenderId"><small><a href=index.php?profile='.$row["nick"].'><b>'.$row["nick"].'</b></a> / <i></i> '.$row["kategori"].'</small>

  </div>

 <a href=index.php?postt='.$row["comment_id"].'&konu='.$row["post_head"].'&kategori='.$row["kategori"].'>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="overflow:none;">

        <img style="width:100%;max-height:350px;overflow:none;padding:5px 0px 10px 0px;" src=upload/'.$row["image"].'>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="more" style="overflow:none;padding-top:5px;"> 
            <h2 class="displayPostHead">'.$post_head.'</h2>
            <p class="displayPostContent">'.substr($row["comment"],0,400).''.$readmore.'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</a>
<div class="footerContent">
<div class="arrows">
<small class="rakam">'.$row["liked"].'</small>

  <a data-id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" data="'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'" class="arrow up" data-val="1"><img src="liked.png" /></a>
  &emsp;
   <a data-id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" class="arrow down" data-val="-1"><img src="dis.png" /></a>
 <small class="rakam">'.$row["unliked"].'</small>
&emsp;<small style="font-family: Germania One, cursive;">Yanıtlar('.$row["totalComments"].')</small> 
</div>

  <div align="right">

     <a style="font-family: Germania One, cursive;color:#0275d8;" href=index.php?postt='.$row["comment_id"].'&konu='.$row["post_head"].'&kategori='.$row["kategori"].'>Konuya Git</button></a>
    </div></div>
    </div></div>

 </div>
 ';
}

?>
```

[Here is how it looks with ajax.This is expected look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZCzv.png)

[And here is how it looks with include function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykK5n.png)

Comment: pls post the `fetch_comment.php` code

Comment: @Tito Okay I added it to my question

Comment: Ok thx so also can u send a snapshot of how it looks now

Comment: @Tito First time I added image.But can you see it?

Comment: Let me be honest.The code looks like a mess.You should really consider a MVC pramework like [laravel](http://laravel.com) for readbility

Comment: @Tito Well,it was something I have been thinking about but wouldnt it take so long time to learn laravel and code the whole project with it?There are too many features in my project

Comment: dudi, you dont really have to learn laravel....  just take up the basics and flow with it.

Comment: What complex features does the project have?

Comment: I can guidee you

Comment: Any help will be appriciated.I can send you my live sites link but I cant start chat with you.How can we contact?I really need your guidance

Comment: well I have facebook, email whatsapp which would u like

Comment: Do u have facebook?

Comment: Yes . Duhan Gökkaya .There is only one account in my name already so you will easily find.I wont take your too much time really,just a few tips

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Duhan+G%C3%B6kkaya&rlz=1C1CHWL_enNG821NG821&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=vjLDKCACpgL6GM%253A%252CcZdTVnSq7hO5eM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQOdY4RMqh_Km7aFwAzqzN1rMN7Ww&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJzbjA-PziAhVzRhUIHZAYB-YQ9QEwA3oECAUQBg#imgrc=vjLDKCACpgL6GM:   is that you?

Comment: I accepted and texted to you

Comment: thx.  but why do you take so long to respond?